# In Clojure why use :only []

Tags: clojure

The source for [lazy-xml](https://github.com/richhickey/clojure-contrib/blob/bbe248f90e6ec33d5e85d2267fa1caf8c7cb99a7/src/main/clojure/clojure/contrib/lazy_xml.clj#L15) has the following:

```
(:use [clojure.xml :as xml :only []]
      [clojure.contrib.seq :only [fill-queue]])
```

What is the purpose of using `clojure.xml` but listing nothing for the `:only` arguments?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Notice the `:as xml` which when combined with the `:only []` seems to make that line equivalent to `(:require [clojure.xml :as xml])`.  That style might be useful if you want to copy some vars into the local namespace (i.e., a non-empty `:only`), but allow the rest of that namespace to be explicitly aliased via `:as`.  Since that's not what he's doing, it really should just be a `:require`.

Comment: Probably the person writing this code has a bunch of `:use` declarations already and didn't want to write a separate `:require` clause. Not a recommended decision IMO, but if he only has one namespace that he's using in this way it would save him a couple characters.

Comment: Code smell? I wonder why the language designer(s) did not opt to have a *single* (combined) use/require form.

Comment: @SridharRatnakumar What. That "I wonder" question doesn't make sense. The `ns` macro is a combined use/require form, and you have to specify somehow which part you want interpreted as a `use`, and which as a `require`. He couldn't just magically guess.

Comment: @amalloy - My question was more like "why do we *need* a separate `use` and `require` functionality in the first place"?

Comment: I did a little research myself and discovered this new syntax that could unify use/require: https://github.com/stuartsierra/need

Comment: Note that as of Clojure 1.4, require can take a :refer option: https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/changes.md#213-require-can-take-a-refer-option